# date countdown not working as intended. time keeps printing

Tags: python, datetime

I have made a script to show the difference between today's date and a date you put in and ended it with the print function and an f string.

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()
print("Please enter the date you want to find out how many days until below: ")
year = int(input("What year? "))
month = int(input("What month? "))
day = int(input("What day? "))


date2 = datetime(year, month, day)

difference = date2 - today

print(f"There are only {difference.days+1} days left until {date2} from {today}")
```

it prints the correct data however it shows the time aswell.
so it shows this as an example:
"There are only 96 days left until 2023-02-23 00:00:00 from 2022-11-19 00:14:18.003365"

how do I remove the time?
also if there are any other suggestions on improving this I'm all ears.

Comment: You tell it what format you want.  `date2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `date` for this calculation.

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
print("Please enter the date you want to find out how many days until below: ")
year = int(input("What year? "))
month = int(input("What month? "))
day = int(input("What day? "))


date2 = date(year, month, day)

difference = date2 - today

print(f"There are only {difference.days+1} days left until {date2} from {today}")
```